# Is it possible to abstract Func declaration?

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I have a method call in two class which look almost identical:

```
public override async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsync(
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> queryShaper, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

and

```
public override async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsync(
    Func<ISqoQuery<TEntity>, ISqoQuery<TEntity>> queryShaper, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I'd really like to combine the signature (so that I don't have to have two interfaces by doing something like :

```
public override async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsync(
    IQueryShaper queryShaper, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{


}
```

and have a function on `IQueryShaper` which returns the correct `Func<>` declaration based on an implementation ?

Does something like this look possible ? Anyone have any ideas how I might be able to achieve my objective ?

Comment: Looks possible to me. Good luck!

Comment: Without specifics on `ISqoQuery`, I don't think you'll get someone to give you specifics.  But, at first glance it would appear that you could simply create a new interface (`IQuerySharper<T>`, you'll need for it to be generic if you don't provide more detail)) with two methods on it, like `IQueryable<TEntity> QueryOne(IQueryable<TEntity>)` and `ISqoQuery<TEntity> QueryTwo(ISqoQuery<TEntity>)`